# i cant get my fos-user table to update new fields

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Okay I am new here,

Well kind off been browsing already for a long time.

I am doing something wrong and i can't see it.

I am using symony 2.8.something
I have installed Fos User Bundle (great works)

done some configuring

```
app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Prox\AdminBundle\Entity\User
```

my User Entity

```
namespace Prox\AdminBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100,nullable=true)
     */
    private $firstname;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100,nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastname;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255,nullable=true)
     */
    private $profilepic;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

    /**
     * Get firstname
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstname
     * @param string $firstname
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFirstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastname
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastname()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastname
     * @param string $lastname
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
        return $this;
    }

    /**Get profilepic
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProfilepic()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $profilepic
     * @return User
     */
    public function setProfilepic($profilepic)
    {
        $this->profilepic = $profilepic;
        return $this;
    }
```

my app Prox/AdminBundle/Resources/config/doctrine

```
Prox\AdminBundle\Entity\User:
    type:  entity
    table: fos_user
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
    firstname:
                type: string
                length: 100
    lastname:
                type: string
                length: 100
    profilepic:
                type: string
                length: 255
```

So this is the given codes and yes also added to app Kernel

when i am runing schema:update --force

It states the db is already in sync. logs confirm tat my annotations are not being picked up.

In short what am i forgetting, my google precious gave me lot's of tips but none worked and i am not seeing it. What more do i have to check

Comment: It might be possible that the annotation related error is coming from route and not fos. Can you give an example of the error you are seeing?

Comment: Try clearing the cache for prod & dev. It used to happen to me sometimes I think it is a cache issue but I'm not sure it is symfony's.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the mapping; you are using Yaml (actually annotations as well? You can only use one of them to start with) but FOS UserBundle uses XML for the mapping of the User entity/table. The documentation reads it can only use one mapping format I believe.